# error when replace with str_replace and preg_replace

Tags: php

I have this string :

```
$x = "&#hello&";
```

I want to change it to something like this :

```
$x = "<span>\hello</span>";
```

this is solution to do that :

```
$x = str_replace("#", "\\", $x);
$x = preg_replace("/&/", "<span>", $x, 1);
$x = preg_replace("/&/", "</span>", $x, -1);
```

but it doesnt work!

any help?

Comment: You should get the expected result: `<span>\hello</span>`, [demo](https://eval.in/216275).

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What exactly is it doing that is different from what you expect? You made reference to an error in your title: which error are you getting?

Comment: Works well for me, however your approach is a little strange. Could you give a more concrete example of what you are trying to do.